# US Citizen overstaying in the Philippines

Tags: us-citizens, overstaying, philippines

I'm a US Citizen and I have been staying in the Philippines for 16 years; my parents could not afford to pay the penalty. What am I going to do? Any suggestions?

Comment: Consult a lawyer. On second thought, consult a lawyer. Seems too delicate a situation to have strangers over the internet tell you what to do.

Comment: How old are you?

Comment: Itai has a good suggestion. If you cannot do that, talk to the US embassy.

Comment: Have you been renewing your US passport while you were there?  Or has it expired?  Are your parents in the Philippines as well or are they simply your only source of money?  There are some many factors that will come into play, your best bet is, as Itai and o.m. said, talk to a lawyer and the US Embassy.